# Can I do anova with only one replication?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, statsmodels

```
def anova_analysis():
  datafile = "test3.csv"

  data = pd.read_csv(datafile, header=0)
  print(data)
  moore_lm = ols('Y ~ C(A, Sum)*C(B, Sum)',
               data=data).fit()

  table = sm.stats.anova_lm(moore_lm, typ=2)  # Type 2 ANOVA DataFrame
  print(table)
  return table

Y   A   B   AB
28  -1  -1  1
36  1   -1  -1
18  -1  1   -1
31  1   1   1
25  -1  -1  1
32  1   -1  -1
19  -1  1   -1
30  1   1   1
27  -1  -1  1
32  1   -1  -1
23  -1  1   -1
29  1   1   1
```

Why will this data work with >4 rows data only?
If I design a 2 factor full factorial table and do only 1 replication it will look like this

```
Y   A   B   AB
28  -1  -1  1
36  1   -1  -1
18  -1  1   -1
31  1   1   1
```

but statsmodel fails with

> File
>   "/home/dsb_mac/anaconda2/envs/bayes/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py",
>   line 1033, in asarray_chkfinite
>       "array must not contain infs or NaNs")
>   ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Answer (score 1):

You get perfect fitin the case with 4 observations. With interaction effect you have 4 parameters so you can perfectly fit 4 cells. With perfect fit the residual variance is zero and the nan or inf come most likely from a ZeroDivision.

Type 2 ANOVA with only main effects should work, but there is most likely no code path to handle the corner case in the perfect fit model.

To get the main effects ANOVA you could use the formula without interaction effect

`'Y ~ C(A, Sum) + C(B, Sum)'`

Comment: Thanks, a lot. Is it possible to show interaction effects similar to [this](https://imgur.com/a/KLtQbuD)? This is 4 factors/2 levels with interaction, 1 replication. The analysis is outputted by Statistica. I tried
  'Y ~ C(A, Sum)*C(B, Sum)*C(C, Sum)' on a different file with dummy data but it returned a TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

Comment: I guess you mean statsmodels and not Statistica. `C` is not a good name for a variable, the formula interpretation in patsy doesn't know whether C should be the coding command or the explanatory variable, and based on the TypeError interprets the `C` as variable name. `Q`uoting might help.

Comment: I think it is not possible to get any inferential statistic, like standard errors in the perfect fit case. With interaction effect you are essentially estimating a mean with a single observations.

Comment: If I interpret the Statistica output in the link correctly, then they don't use the all interaction model, i.e. R-squared is smaller than one. My guess is that they only look at pairwise interactions in the 4 factor model but do not include interaction between 3 and 4 factors. That should be possible also in statsmodels.

Comment: Thanks, for your input. If I simply copy and pasted the observation Y data to get 8 values will I get essentially the same analysis but avoiding the error?